How can I connect 120V outlets to a #10 cable on a 30A breaker?
I re-sided my house and needed to upgrade the outside main electrical panel, which I had an electrician do.  I wanted a dedicated outlet(s) in my garage for my table saw etc which often trips the breaker it is in now.
So while there were no walls, I ran a 10/2 orange romex from the garage to the outside main panel and the electrician terminated it into a 30amp breaker.
So now I have a 30 amp line to the garage but I am not sure how to terminate it. I perhaps should have run 10/3 or just 12/2 but I didn’t. I have 10/2. How do i terminate or convert so that I can have 2-4 outlets for regular 110/120 usage? Do I need a sub panel or is there a way to terminate into a standard type outlet? I thought I could get an outlet to take 30 instead of 20 or 15 but I don’t think that’s right. Can you provide some direction on what I can do or have done next?

Is the table saw 120V or 240V? 120V would be the happy answer.

You could change the breaker to a 20 amp. Then splice to #12 cable in a junction box in the garage and run #12 cable to wherever you want outlets.

And label the 30A cable at the panel as for 20A use only.

Most subpanels expect two hots, which you don't have.
You can use a regular subpanel but can only use half of the breaker spaces (most simple setup).
From the top it will be the first space, skip the second, use the third, etc.  If using more than one space.
Most places now require GFCI protection on garage receptacles, either breaker or receptacle.

Yes, if you want a 20 or 15 amp outlet from a 30 amp supply, you need a subpanel between them with a 15 or 20 amp breaker.
